# JRebel forbidding reloading of class

Tags: java, server, weblogic, jrebel

I started using JRebel on a remote server. I see the class being updated in the exploded EAR on the remote server.

When I debug, it actually didn't really get updated in the app. In the JRebel logs I have found this message:

> [DebuggerIntegration] Start checkAndReload(class com.app.SomeService)
>
> [Licensing-Remote] RemotingLicensing: is reloading allowed? className = com.app.SomeService, reloadedFromUrl = file:/D:/blablabla/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/SomeService.class
>
> [Licensing-Remote] Forbidding reloading of class 'com.app.SomeService' - haven't seen a single authenticated IDE transaction!
>
> [DebuggerIntegration] End checkAndReload(class com.app.SomeService), time=2ms

Any ideas please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep. Contact their support. Seriously, they answer quickly most of the time; and they know their stuff. But well, as most of their folks are in Estonia, Europe, you shouldnt expect answers before Monday ;-) But just to be sure, you got a valid licence, and our IDE is all happy about JRebel?

Comment: To double check, the remote server and IDE are on different file system? If yes, how was the class file updated on the server? Via Remote Server synchronization feature in IDE or by some other means?